# What is the pythonic/faster way to check if the "key" argument of a custom __getitem__ method is a slice?

Tags: python, slice, magic-methods, typechecking

I have a custom Sequence type. It is essentially a wrapper for a list plus a boolean flag and I wanted it to emulate usual immutable sequence behavior.

My issue is with slicing. I understand that in Python 3 the way to implement it is to have a `__getitem__(key)` method that returns an item if `%key` is a single index and a sliced sequence if `%key` is a slice object. But how should I discriminate these cases?

I basically have two hypotheses.

```
sliced_list = self.wrapped_list[key]
if isinstance(key, slice):
    return MyCustomSequenceType(sliced_list, boolean_flag)
return sliced_list
```

But this is evil, isn't it? Or

```
sliced_list = self.wrapped_list[key]
try:
    return MyCustomSequenceType(sliced_list, boolean_flag)
except TypeError:
    return sliced_list
```

The latter looks more pythonic. It relies on the fact that `MyCustomSequenceType.__init__(self, datas, flag)` calls len(datas), it so raise `TypeError` if `%datas` is an `integer`. But then, if `__init__` raises `TypeError` for another random issue  it will be untraceable. Also http://wiki.cython.org/enhancements/numpy/getitem hints that `isinstance` is faster (in fact more easily optimizable).

What should I do, then?

Comment: I don't think `isinstance` is evil in this case. It has enough non-evil uses to be included in Python (unlike goto), and this is probably one of them.

Comment: Well, it turned me into a newt.

Comment: Well, I guess that's evil. Unless you'd done something to deserve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could have a look through the standard library and copy what is done there. For example, calendar.py has:

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    funcs = self._months[i]
    if isinstance(i, slice):
        return [f(self.format) for f in funcs]
    else:
        return funcs(self.format)
```

which shows both explicit checking with `isinstance` *and* partially ducking the issue by simply passing the index or slice through to the underlying list.

Comment: Pretty obvious indeed. Well, I'm still not used to Python stdlib organisation. I'll take a closer look next time. Thanks.

Comment: But I'd rather skip the `else:` statement. If `isinstance(i, slice)
` bumped `True`, the first `return` statement already occurred and the second won't be reached.

Answer (score 2):

That should be `isinstance(key, slice)`, not `isinstance(key, "slice")`.

Also, you shouldn't call `__getitem__` directly - use the `[]` item notation.

For myself, I *would* use the `isinstance(key, slice)` method if I needed to discern - `slice` is a pretty special thing, not something that's easily going to be replaceable with another type (think about it - if `self.wrapped_list` is a `list`, a `slice` is the only type of object which will return other than an element or error).

So I'd end up with it like this:

```
sliced_list = self.wrapped_list[key]
if isinstance(key, slice):
    return MyCustomSequenceType(sliced_list, boolean_flag)
return sliced_list
```

Consider further though whether you need to treat slices specially; I have no idea what your case is, but when making an architectural decision which will influence things later, it's generally a good idea to consider a few different ways of doing the same thing and evaluate them all and decide on the best one (not that I do it much myself - I tend to just rush in and implement and patch afterwards...).

Comment: Well I thought using `__getitem__` made sense since the use of a standard `list` was not meant to be restrictive, but of course any object which implements it support bracketed notation too, you're right. 
The need to treat slices specially stem from the need of returning an instance of `MyCustomSequenceType` if `%key` was a slice and an element of `wrapped_list` if it was merely a single index. I couldn't think of a better way to do it.
Thanks anyway. The Java dev in me praise the type-orientedness of this solution.

Comment: Also I edited question to `isinstance(key, slice)` in order to not confuse potential readers into doing the same mistake.